# Regular Expression vs Scripting Language for maintainability requirement

Tags: c#, regex, validation, vbscript

For the requirement of doing validations (range, invalid characters, length, list), would it be better to use regular expressions or scripting language (C# or VBScript) from the standpoint of maintainability? The maintainability here means providing fix without needing to recompile.

e.g. Regular expressions can be stored in database and then changed without recompiling the code? We can also achieve the same thing by using scripting language and providing the script files either by storing in database or as separate files?

I am leaning towards using scripting language instead of regular expressions as I do not have good knowledge of regular expressions.

Would some validation framework (e.g. Patterns n Practices) be better as compared to above two approaches? I would still want to avoid using regular expressions in using validation framework?

Answer (score 1):

There is an abundance of information on regular expressions all over the internet.

Regex can be used to validate strings quite easily. I can help you with that if you would like to tell me some validation patterns that you need to perform.

Answer (score 1):

I would use regular expression for the reasons you mention. Regex is an universal language (with some dialects), while scripting is implementation specific. Ask yourself: Who will maintain your code in the future and will (s)he have more knowledge of the provided scripting language or regular expressions.

Another advantage of regular expression is that they are quite easy to test with all kind of tools (even online), while scripting always needs test code or a working test environment where you have to prepare your start situation to do some testing.